# Tableau - Internal server error when running in batch file

Tags: batch-file, tableau-api

I am trying to automate tableau downloading and publishing using windows batch file(.bat).

The login command which runs perfectly when executed on command line and it creates exception when included as a `.bat` file.

```
tabcmd login -s https://mytableauserver -u "myuser" -p mypassword
```

which returns with exception as follows

```
===== Creating new session
=====     Server:   https://mytableauserver
=====     Username: myuser
===== Connecting to the server...
  *** Internal server error
PersistenceException
```

When executed on command line returns

```
===== Creating new session
=====     Server:   https://mytableauserver
=====     Username: myuser
===== Connecting to the server...
===== Signing in...
===== Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you embed credentials in the workbooks you are publishing to tableau server? You would do this in "Scheduling and Authentication" when publishing the first copy to the server.